# Does java automatically close AutoClosable-s declared in try block body?

Tags: java, try-catch, try-with-resources

I have the following code

```
try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(path))){
    while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
        Scanner delimit = new Scanner(scanner.nextLine()).useDelimiter("-");
        ...
    }
}
...
```

I understand that the scanner in parentheses will be closed automatically, however I never explicitly close `delimit` and I get no warning about a resource leak. So does Java automatically close any `AutoClosable`-s declared in try block body or is this a bug and I should be getting a resource leak warning?

Comment: No it doesn't, but not every Scanner *needs* to be closed.

Comment: But the strange thing is that if I move the scanner outside of try block the resource leak warning appears...

Comment: If you move the Scanner outside of the try block, it obviously can’t use `scanner.nextLine()`.  So what does the code look like when it’s outside of the try block?  A Scanner only needs to be closed if a closeable resource is passed to the Scanner constructor.

Answer (score 0):

No, java wont close every resource declared in body. Java automatically will close the resources declared with try so you can change your code to like below, then java will close it automatically -

```
try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(path))){
while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
    try (Scanner delimit = new Scanner(scanner.nextLine()).useDelimiter("-")){
    ...
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I understand but why don't I get a resource leak warning then?

Comment: Because closing of resource is handled now, you will get a resource leak warning only if in any scenario your declared resource might not get closed but declaring with try will give you guarantee that resources will be closed even if there is exception/error in your code except system exit case.

Comment: I meant in my original code, not in yours